# Twitter API call to get access_token of OAuth only with javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to figure if I can authenticate users with Twitter OAuth in one simple ajax call. I need to use javascript because I am building the application on iOS with Phonegap. Here is the api used for Facebook to directly retrieve the access_token for that user once they sign in and authorize app.

What would be the Twitter equivalent of this API call if there is one?

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
   &response_type=token
```

I have already tried applying the 3 legged authentication, to no avail of course. I prefer not using the pin authorization method.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth) meet your needs. According to Twitter, "xAuth allows desktop and mobile applications to skip the request_token and authorize steps and jump right to the access_token step." The only caveat is that you need to request permission from Twitter for your app to use xAuth.

Comment: The problem with xAuth is that I need to request the user's username and password within my application and post it to Twitter.

Comment: Yep. But it's really the only option for skipping to the access_token step on Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for Mark S's as xAuth is a compelling option for user experience and ease of implementation. If you can get Twitter to approve it I would definitely do that.

You could also register your iOS app with a [custom URL](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) that you can use as a callback from the authorization step. This would allow you to receive the oauth_verifier directly to your app without going via a user entering a PIN.

Another tip is to simply scrape the oauth_verifier from any valid callback. Once the WebView loads it you can check the WebView's address property for the oauth_verifier parameter. Once the verifier is yours you will be able to get the access token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jon. I am currently getting the oauth_verifier by using a separate browser window. But when I try and call Twitter's API to get the access_token, nothing happens. It just breaks. Thats why im looking for alternatives at this point.